# AWS Lambda: Python user input possible?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, aws-lambda, headless-browser

I am trying to create an AWS lambda function that help user collect data from a website (using selenium and headless-chromium). The website requires sms code verification during login so I need to get it from the user and pass it back to the AWS Lambda function

the flow will be:

1. username & password send to lambda function
2. lambda function start, chromium auto login with username & password
3. waiting for sms code from user
4. user enter sms code, code pass to lambda function
5. lambda function continue

is it possible to do so? like the input() function when running python locally

thanks!!

*first question in stackoverflow! let me know if anything doesn't make sense

Comment: why isn't it posible ?

Comment: how do you plan to provide input?

Comment: Generally no: lambdas are stateless and do not wait for (user) input. You would need to split your logic into multiple lambdas or at least multiple lambda invocations and come up with a system to transfer state between different invocations.

Comment: thanks guys,  unfortunately I can't split my logic coz the sms input page only appear after username and password entered (which mean lambda already started), thanks luk2303 let me look into multiple lambda invocations and see if it helps !!

Comment: Take a look into AWS Step Functions' [Callback Pattern Example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/callback-task-sample-sqs.html) with API Gateway Integration, there might be a possibility there but again as @luk2302  said you need to change your workflow a bit and services you'll use on the AWS side to achieve this.

Comment: @samtoddler Thanks for giving me a direction!  just wondering should I look into using AWS ec2? Seems like lambda wasn't the right fit for my case?

Comment: @Ivan1221 suit yourself, what I see from [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-service-integrations.html) EC2  is not a supported services for aws step functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need at least two Lambdas.

Second Lambda:

- Takes OTP & UserId as input.
- Writes a record to DynamoDb with userId and OTP.

First Lambda:

- Lambda is invoked with user Id and password
- Start a selenium browser session.
- Login and write a record to Dynamo.
- Keep checking Dynamo every second for an entry for userId with OTP in Dynamo.
- Set a timeout and complete Login Process.

Main disadvantage of this approach is we have first Lambda running for entire time of login. But if we can't break the login and OTP process, I don't see another way.
May be having a ECS Fargate task instead of Lambda function may save some cost as we can easily run multiple selenium browser sessions in single ECS Task.

Comment: thanks! let me try out your 2 lambda method and take a look into ecs fargate! AWS still very new to me really appreciate your help

Comment: 2 lambda method worked! I simplified it with one lambda keep checking s3 bucket for sms code file and a direct s3 upload.from user.

Comment: Great. @Ivan1221